# How can I x11 forward from docker to the host inside a virtual machine then to the localhost

Tags: virtualbox, docker, container

Here is the scenario

```
program (inside container) -> virtual machine -> localhost
```

I'm using a mac os as a host and boot up a virtual machine using virtual box. Inside virtual box, I boot up a container containing a program with GUI. Is there a way to do X11 forwarding to my mac os host?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using `DISPLAY` environment variable should be enough to go from container -> VM.

Then on the VM use `socat` to listen on the TCP and connect to the X11 unix socket (`/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` ) or abstract unix socket (@/tmp/.X11-unix/X0).

Alternate to socat, use `xhost +{container}` and configure Xorg on the VM to listen to a network address.